# Unix command to capitalize first letter of file name

Tags: unix, command-line, replace, filenames

I have a folder "activity" which contains files like getEmployee.java, getTable.java etc. I was wondering if there was a unix command that could replace the file Name to give me: GetEmployee.java, GetTable.java and so on.

I've tried `mv getEmployee.java GetEmployee.java`

However this is pretty cumbersome as you can imagine since i have almost 70 files. Is there a way in Unix I can do this? I usually use `sed` to replace stuff, but I don't think that works for filenames. Can someone please suggest an easier way please?

Comment: What shell are you using? For example, this is a bit easier with Bash 4.x than with Bash 3.x.

Comment: GNOME shell I believe. In rhel5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a shell script that will find *.java files in the local directory and alter them:

```
#!/bin/sh

find . -name "*.java" -print | gawk -F "/" '
{
    new = sprintf( "%s%s", toupper( substr( $NF, 1, 1 ) ), substr( $NF, 2 ) )

    cmd = sprintf( "mv %s %s", $NF, new )

    # comment out the next two lines and uncomment the printf() to see the commands
    cmd | getline ret_val
    close( cmd )

    #printf( "%s => ret_val = %s\n", cmd, ret_val"" )
} '
```

I saved it to a script named "alterjava", "chmod +x alterjava" then ran it on a directory of zero sized files I made up for testing.  You can check the commands before running it by commenting out the cmd line and uncommenting the printf() line

Answer (score 3):

Bash can perform case-replacement in parameter substitution, using `${^}` to capitalise the first character:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.java; do mv -v "$i" "${i^}"; done
```

Note that this is not standard POSIX; other shells need not have this feature

Answer (score 0):

```
rename -vn 's/([a-z])(\w+.java)/\u$1$2/' *.java
```

remove -n to execute command

Comment: Outputs `'filename.java' not renamed: 'Filename.java' already exists` for all files on macOS High Sierra with homebrew version of `rename`